# Typescript override generic property

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
class Base<T> {}

class Test {
  prop: Base<any>;

  createProp<T>() {
    this.prop = new Base<T>();
  }
}

const test = new Test();

test.createProp<{ a: number }>();

test.prop // Base<any> expected Base<{ a: number }>
```

When I call `createProp` with the generic, I want it to be the new type of the `prop` property. Currently, after running this method, the type is still - `Base<any>`. There is a way to do it with TS?

Answer (score 1):

`prop` is defined as `Base<any>` - it’ll never be a `Base<T>`, even if one is assigned to it.

In order to achieve this behaviour, you’ll have to make your *class* generic instead of  just the method:

```ts
class Base<T> {}

class Test<T> {
  prop: Base<T>;

  createProp() {
    this.prop = new Base<T>();
  }
}

const test = new Test<{ a: number }>();

test.createProp();

test.prop
```

Alternatively, if you’re *really* against using a generic class, you could use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions):

```ts
class Base<T> {}

class Test {
  prop: Base<any>;

  createProp<T>() {
    this.prop = new Base<T>();
  }
}

const test = new Test();

test.createProp<{ a: number }>();

test.prop as Base<{ a: number }>
// --- or ---
<Base<{ a: number }>> test.prop
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that I can do it like that, but I thought there be might a way to do it as I want.

Comment: Ah fair enough. You could cast the returned value, since you know its type from the generic on `createProp`. It’s a little messy but it would save you from creating a generic class if you’re trying to avoid it